# Useful folder structure for Project-Euler (Make/Source)?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm currently trying to come up with a reliable folder structure for `Project-Euler`.

My current idea is this structure:

```
.
└── project-euler/
    ├── resources
    │   ├── primes.h
    │   ├── primes.c
    │   ├── factors.h
    │   ├── factors.c
    │   └── ...
    ├── 001_name_of_procect_one.c
    ├── 001_name_of_project_one.o
    ├── 002_name_of_project_two.c
    ├── 002_name_of_project_two.o
    └── ...
```

My problem with this structure is that I have all the projects in one folder and I don't know how to write `Makefiles` for this kind of structure.

I could create a separate directory for every project, but then I would have to write something like `#include "../resources/primes.h"` and I somehow don't like this approach.

What is the typical project structure to use in such a case? How would I be able to write a `Makefile` for all the small projects while still keeping them in the same directory?

EDIT: I use `clang` by the way.

Comment: I tackle project Euler problems. Every problem is attempted using a source file called euler.c and the same makefile. Once I have finished with a problem, I rename the source file as say euler-42.c and copy it to an archive folder. If I am working on a problem similar to an earlier one, I start with that one's source code. Simple.

Comment: Project Euler is such a humbling experience!  Once you finish a problem, make sure you look at the solutions previous winners posted on the forum, very very interesting.

Comment: @chqrlie Yeah, I already did solve quite a few problems, but just randomly. Now I want to create a nice library with nice functions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep utility files in the `resources` subdirectory, you can create individual solution files in the main directory that include the necessary header files at the top with eg:

```
#include "resources/primes.h"
```

And include the actual code at the bottom with

```
#include "resources/primes.c"
```

This way, you do not even need a `Makefile` as the default rules will allow you to make each target from the corresponding source file directly:

```
make 002_name_of_project_two
```

make will not even produce the object file, just the executable.

I personally name prefer shorter names for the project files, such as `p42.c`

The `Makefile` is still useful to hit just `make` or the build button of your IDE.  A one liner will suffice:

```
all: p42
```

But you might want to add some dependencies so your target recompiles when you only change the utility sources.  Add these lines: (with a TAB at the beginning of the second line)

```
%: %.c $(wildcard resources/*)
    clang $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

You still should add the proper options to your `CFLAGS` environment variable to take advantage of the compilers ability to catch silly mistakes: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` for `gcc`, and `-Weverything` for `clang`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I'll probably go this way :)

Comment: Sorry, it's a fresh account and I still can't upvote. I just noticed that I can accept answers though :)

Answer (score 0):

If your using `g++` you declare an include directory with:

```
g++ -I../resources #rest of command line
```

Answer (score 0):

This extended comment about libraries will be a Philistine answer contrary to usual thinking. In earlier years I spent countless hours maintaining my lovely library, but there are problems involved with the nice idea. Such a library is always a work in progress, but when a project is signed off and delivered, you dare not change the library for fear of breaking previous project(s), so it has to be frozen. You'll then have several versions of your library around. Now, suppose mods are required to an old project, that requires altering a library function? You still cannot use the current version, because you'll have to go through the previous product testing and assurance all over again. Another objection was that some of my supposedly good library functions were never quite what I wanted in the next project. The whole thing became a maintenance nightmare and I abandonded it. What I find now, is that in a Project Euler problem I might need a factorial function. In one case, a simple `unsigned` function will be good. In another case, I'll need `uint64_t` to be in range. In yet another, that will be either `unsigned` or `uint64_t` modulo some constant. The variations are endless, and a general one-function-fits-all approach is inappropriate when the function might need calling millions of times. So I just use a copy/paste solution picking bits I need from other problems.

Comment: I share a substantially similar experience, but some utility functions are too useful to throw away and tricky to get right.  Sharing the code and honing it at will does improve productivity.  Using `git` helps a lot with branching old code and backporting new ideas and bug fixes.

Comment: You are probably right! This brings a whole new aspect to me. Thank you for your answer.